# Firebase Realtime Database Privacy best practice

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security

I'm playing with Firebase Realtime Database and after a while I start wondering if there are best practice to structure the database for privacy.

I mean, I see best practice for performance like database fan-out

```
Map updatedUser = new HashMap();
newPost.put("name", "Shannon");
newPost.put("username": "shannonrules");

Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");

Map fanoutObject = new HashMap();
fanoutObject.put("/users/1", updatedUser);
fanoutObject.put("/usersWhoAreCool/1", updatedUser);
fanoutObject.put("/usersToGiveFreeStuffTo/1", updatedUser);

ref.updateChildren(fanoutObject); // atomic updating goodness
```

But I did found nothing about privacy polices.

I know there are Database ACL that I can use to, for example, restrict access to users not authenticate or users there are not the "owner" of a particular node... but for those nodes that are readable someone could be, if he would, access the entire children of those nodes.

Suggestions?

EDIT: Database rules are not descendant so if I let users read a node they alway can read all nodes below:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "foo": {
        // allows read to /foo/*
        ".read": "data.child('baz').val() === true",
        "bar": {
          /* ignored, since read was allowed already */
          ".read": false
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: bar has read false, but ur getting read true?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yep 'cause is under foo that has read = true. Look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Comment: weird it worked with me, did u test it using the simulator in the security rules?

Comment: @PeterHaddad How come it worked if the documentation says it must not work?

Comment: nevermind, it doesnt work, I was not adding bar as nested child

Comment: @PeterHaddad okay, now we are aligned ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can secure your database using [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

> Firebase Realtime Database Rules determine who has read and write access to your database, how your data is structured, and what indexes exist. These rules live on the Firebase servers and are enforced automatically at all times. Every read and write request will only be completed if your rules allow it. By default, your rules are set to allow only authenticated users full read and write access to your database. This is to protect your database from abuse until you have time to customize your rules or set up authentication.

All your requirements can be met using security rules.

Comment: Yes, I've read but since these rules are not descendant: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade It's not so easy have a good ACL policy.

Comment: Is not so easy but is not impossible. You can use specific rules to achieve everything you want. I can also take a look at [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt).

Comment: It's true, It's not so easy. Anyway I'll give you the right answer and we'll see if someone we'll give us some new hits in the future. Hope you'll like my question too ;)

Comment: Good question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you need ACL style security, take a look at [Custom Auth Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) - using Cloud Functions you can add your own properties to a user's JWT auth token, e.g. to say which groups they belong to or which products they have purchased. Then your security rules can look at those properties upon the user and decide if they can access a particular node.